# Scheduling of GAE instances and JDO initialisation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I know the GAE scheduler is the subject of much scrutiny and attention.  I also know it is critical to the performance of my application.  I have spent the last week optimising and analysing my application.

I also understand that the scheduler is designed to work across the gamut of application sizes, and the algorithm may not be optimised for my relatively smaller scale application, in terms of concurrent users.

I believe the following description of pending latency is wrong, which leads to unavoidable delays:

> The Pending Latency slider controls how long requests spend in the
>   pending queue before being served by an Instance of the default
>   version of your application. If the minimum pending latency is high
>   App Engine will allow requests to wait rather than start new Instances
>   to process them. This can reduce the number of instance hours your
>   application uses, but can result in more user-visible latency.

How can it possibly be the case that with a pending latency of 15 seconds, and 2 idle instances, when I execute 10 requests in serial, all taking 1-3 seconds (with mutli-threading enabled), that it spins up new instances?

Why do I care?  I could just put all my intialisation in my warmup code?  Wrong.  I am using GAE/J with JDO.  It seems that the FIRST time EACH INSTANCE hits an ENTITY TYPE the  very FIRST time it incurs a "validation" overhead of a few seconds.  Most of the time you won't even know this is happening unless you set your JDO logging to INFO level.

**My question is the following:**

**Has anyone else experienced the following situation relating to scheduler behaviour and it's interaction with DS initialisation, and if so, can you suggest a solution so that I may avoid incurring such delays?**

Specifically, the situation is:

- With JDO - Each time a new instance 'touches' an entity type for the first time it incurs an initialisation overhead (if you are in doubt set your JDO logging level to INFO).  This overhead is of the order of 2-3 secs
- The increased latency as a result of this overhead, coupled with the fact that the scheduler clearly ignores the Pending Latency parameters means it is more likely to spin up a new instance than calculate that existing instances can handle the request.
- because the new request is being handled by a new instance the initialisation overhead described above is REPEATED.  Thus the vicious circle is perpetuated.

Note that I have already considered the following remedies:

1. migrate to hibernate or similar - a huge undertaking and unclear if it will solve problems.
2. modify my application architecture to use Backends to deliver all DB functionality as at least I can control how many I have running etc.
3. perhaps there is some JDO config I am missing that will simply avoid the above-mentioned overhead?

Comment: Could you please point out, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi Pavel, yes fair enough I didn't ask a clear question, I will edit.

Comment: Hi doright, I was thinking that your question might be more useful if you focus on asking for a *solution* rather than simply trying to get others to confirm the problem exists. Confirming it's existence doesn't really help solve the problem, but I think with an [edit] to your question, this could prove to be useful to other Java App Engine developers facing the same problem. Hope this helps! Good luck! :)

Comment: thanks jmort253, updated again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JDO will cause delays when you first access it. This is due to the JDO spec requiring the implementation be able to provide information that can only be gathered by introspection of the DB; even if you don't want the information, it still has to gather it. My advice, as for anyone using Java on App Engine, is to not use JDO - use something better suited to App Engine, like Objectify.

It's unlikely the pending latency settings are what's causing new instances to be spun up in your situation; far more likely is the Min Idle instances; if this is greater than 0, as soon as an instance is occupied with a request, the scheduler will spin up an extra one.

Comment: Nick, many thanks. You raise some interesting points here, can I press you for some more info please?  So you confirm that its EACH new instance that takes hit with EACH entity Type it accesses? Because this is a HUGE limiation of GAE and goes completely against the flexible instances paradigm surely? JDO is basically un-usable for serious applications in that case.  Secondly if I move to objectify can I run JDO and Objectify in parallele during migration? Finally, if I don't have any min idle instances how can I hope to achieve a "hot standby" ie having an instance ready for a request?

Comment: @doright I don't use JDO a great deal, but each instance should only have one slowdown, when you first use JDO. This is not a limitation of App Engine - it's a requirement of JDO. You can indeed use JDO and Objectify side-by-side, as long as you define models that are compatible.

Comment: And min-idle is exactly what you need for a standby instance. When a request comes in that results in fewer than the minimum idle instances being idle, a new instance is spun up and a warmup request is sent to it - which is exactly what you want if you always want to have a warm standby, and it's exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: Hi again Nick.  "but each instance should only have one slowdown, when you first use JDO" Not my experience with JDO.  if you put the log level to info for the DS stuff you will see a huge amount of initialization for each Entity Type that instance needs to use, for any given method, as described in my question.  Which leads onto my question about warm-standby.  Because it seems to favour using a new instance it uses instances which are more often than not subject to the delays mentioned above. (c.f. using my idle instance which would have performed all JDO initialisation already)

Comment: Like I said, I haven't used JDO extensively; I can't speak to when specifically it chooses to load metadata. Nevertheless, I recommend avoiding it for that reason. The App Engine scheduler will not send user requests to a new instance if an existing instance is available and idle.

Comment: thanks Nick.  Seems that my 'pending latency' setting was adversely affecting the scheduler.  I had understood that a high pending latency was telling the scheduler not to favour spinning up a new instance, rather wait until an existing instance was available.  Seems high pending latencies makes it more likely to create a new one.  I am now running much more successfully with Pending Latency set to Auto/1s.  I will migrate away to Objectify, glad to hear I can do that stage by stage.